# Why has an @ApplicationScoped bean a new instance in the BeforeShutdown phase of my CDI extension ?

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I would like to make some clean up on a bean when I shutdown a CDI application. For example, I would like to close an IO connection. Of course, here, the bean is marked as @ApplicationScoped.

To manage this I wrote an extension and observe the BeforeShutdown event, and then I select my bean to call a clean up method :

```
public void beforeShutdown(@Observes BeforeShutdown beforeShutdown) {
    SomeBean obj = CDI.current().select(SomeBean.class).get();
    obj.cleanup();
}
```

My problem is that I have access to a new instance in this method. Not the instance I got in the whole application.

If you want to see this instance problem, I've made a repo on github to show it : https://github.com/hasalex/cdi-extension-demo.

So I have 2 questions :

- Why do I get a new instance ?
- Is there an other way to cleanup my bean at the end of the application ? (in SE and in WildFly environments)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look here: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1.EDR1/html/spi.html#provider

> 11.5.4. BeforeShutdown event
>
> The container must fire a final event after it has finished processing requests and destroyed all contexts.

Maybe you want to use @PreDestroy: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html

> Annotate the declaration of the method with the javax.annotation.PreDestroy annotation.
>
> CDI calls this method before starting to destroy the bean.

Comment: @PreDestroy is much simpler than what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Comment: And if in case your class bean is not annotated but produced by either field or method, you can also use a dispose method to clean your resource before destroying the bean. (public void cleanUp(@Disposes T bean) { bean.cleanup(); } where T is your bean type)